# Firebase só funciona no Unity Editor e no pC não funciona no Android

Tags: android, firebase, unity3d

Alguém sabe me dizer, o que esta ocorrendo de errado? Ele funciona apenas no Unity Editor.
Quando buildo para android, não funciona, mas não informa nenhum tipo de erro. Ao testar no pc funciona normalmente.

```
public void CadastrarPorEmail()
    {
        email = _textEmail.text;
        password = _texSenha.text;


        auth.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password).ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if (task.IsCanceled)
            {
                _imgDeAvisos.SetActive(true);
                _textAviso.text = "Erro ao criar usuário: " + task.Exception;
                Debug.LogWarning("CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync was canceled.");
                return;
            }
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
                _imgDeAvisos.SetActive(true);
                _textAviso.text = "Erro ao criar usuário: " + task.Exception;
                return;
            }

            // Firebase user has been created.
            Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
            Debug.LogFormat("Firebase user created successfully: {0} ({1})", newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);
            _imgDeAvisos.SetActive(true);
            _imgDeAvisos.GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color32(0, 185, 156, 100);
            _textAviso.text = " Cadastro Criado com sucesso !" + newUser.DisplayName + newUser.UserId; 

            //Send Emails Verification
            newUser.SendEmailVerificationAsync().ContinueWith(t => {
            Debug.Log("Verifique o seu e-mail");
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Trabalhei com o sdk firebase e unity recentemente, tive muitos problemas com ele, no editor sempre funcionava certinho e quando dava build não ia. Depois de pesquisar bastante descobri que tem algo nele que da problema com a wifi. Tenta reiniciar o moldem ou usar a 4g/3g do celular pra ver se funciona. Caso não funcione tenta dar um force reolver no playservices resolver e ver se tem algum erro. Da uma verificada no Package name se esta tudo certo também. Se ainda assim houver problema especifique mais os pacotes do firebase que você esta usando pra ver se consigo ajudar de alguma maneira.

[image]

Já tinha feito login com facebook e login com google, acessava e gravava dados no realtime database, tava tudo funcionando, mas sempre tinha que mudar a conexão do celular.

Sinceramente não recomendo ultilizar o firebase com a Unity, tem muitos problemas ainda quando estiver estavel os sdks será perfeito pra muita coisa, perdi varios meses fazendo isso e decidi mudar pra web api própria, atrasei o projeto mas ta funcionando perfeitamente agora.